# object overwrite when it add into a array inside the loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm working  on a algorithm to Transform the array into object. When the last transformed object is overwrite the previous object inside the array.

This is my code:

```
let array = [
    [
        ['firstName', 'Joe'], ['lastName', 'Blow'], ['age', 42], ['role', 'clerk']
    ],
    [
        ['firstName', 'Mary'], ['lastName', 'Jenkins'], ['age', 36], ['role', 'manager']
    ]
];

function transformEmployeeData(array) {
    let obj = {};
    for(let i in array) {
        for(let j in array[i]) {
            obj[array[i][j][0]] = array[i][j][1];
        }
        array.splice(i,1,obj);
    }
    return array;
}

let run = transformEmployeeData(array);
```

I'm expected to get this result as output:

```
[
    {firstName: "Joe", lastName: "Blow", age: 42, role: "clerk"}
    {firstName: "Mary", lastName: "Jenkins", age: 36, role: "manager"}
];
```

Instead of getting this

```
[
    {firstName: "Mary", lastName: "Jenkins", age: 36, role: "manager"},
    {firstName: "Mary", lastName: "Jenkins", age: 36, role: "manager"}
];
```

When I log the the obj, I get the expected result. When I add it into an array it just overwrites the previous result.

Comment: See the dupe target. You'll just need to nest the method one level, since you need an array of objects.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you use the same object over and over and take the last values, because it keeps the reference.

You could initialize `obj` for every loop with an empty object.

For the result, you could use a new array, without mutating the original array.

Just another hint, for iterating an array, you may better use the index and count it up, instead of the `for ... in` syntax: [Why is using “for…in” with array iteration a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea).

```js
var array = [
  [
    ['firstName', 'Joe'],
    ['lastName', 'Blow'],
    ['age', 42],
    ['role', 'clerk']
  ],
  [
    ['firstName', 'Mary'],
    ['lastName', 'Jenkins'],
    ['age', 36],
    ['role', 'manager']
  ]
];

function transformEmployeeData(array) {
  var i, j, temp = [];
  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    let obj = {};
    for (j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
      obj[array[i][j][0]] = array[i][j][1];
    }
    temp.push(obj);
  }
  return temp;
}
let run = transformEmployeeData(array);

console.log(run);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A concise version with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator).

```js
const getKeyValueArray = array =>
       array.map(a => Object.assign(...a.map(([k, v]) => ({ [k]: v }))));

var data = [[['firstName', 'Joe'], ['lastName', 'Blow'], ['age', 42], ['role', 'clerk']], [['firstName', 'Mary'], ['lastName', 'Jenkins'], ['age', 36], ['role', 'manager']]];

console.log(getKeyValueArray(data));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Would it be better to return a new transformed array than modifying the input array parameter and causing side effects?

Comment: Never assume the destructive variant is the desired one.

Comment: right, a new array fits better.

Answer (score 1):

why not replace `splice` with `push` into a new array and return the new one instead?

```
function transformEmployeeData(array)     {
    let returnvalue = [];
  for(let i in array) {
    let obj = {};
    for(let j in array[i]) {
      obj[array[i][j][0]]=array[i][j][1];
    }
    returnvalue.push(obj);
  }
  return returnvalue;
}
```

hope that helps, also when you are iterating try to avoid manipulating the interated array that changes the length to avoid unexpected results i.e. ’splice, push, etc.’